# Error in Veeam Bare Metal Recovery

Tags: veeam

Using Veeam Backup and Recovery v11 Community Edition to do a bare metal recovery of a small form PC (Acer Aspire) and am getting the error below after selecting "Bare Metal Recovery" from the Veeam Recovery Media menu but before the Veeam Recovery Media Wizard displays:

```
Veeam Agent For Microsoft Windows
Server 'localhost' does not exist or access denied. 
Check firewall settings. 
Call was canceled with the message filter. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010002 (RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED))
```

The computer can't boot itself, it is stuck in an endless repair loop. So it was booted from a USB drive made from the recovery media generated from the backup. After the error, a command prompt opens. I know the network connection is active as I can ping the server with the Veeam repository from this command prompt.

I'm at a loss of how to restore the backup, any hints would be appreciated... The Veeam forums can't be used for support questions and being the Community Edition, there is no formal support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of others, the solution was to:

- Wipe the device
- Install a basic unactivated Windows OS
- Install the VBR agent
- Create a recovery disk
- Boot from recovery disk
- Perform bare metal recovery

The original issue was while the recovery disk was created from the device's backup, it wasn't the same/didn't work the same as a recovery disk created on the device itself.

Answer (score -1):

As it seems, you've stored the backup on the VBR server. Since `localhost` refers to the machine itself, you seem to have shot yourself in the foot.

I'm not sure if that option exists, but try to search for the backup image on the local drives, where your backup repository is located.

If you manage to recover, redirect the backup storage for the local Veeam Agent either to a local disk or to a network storage that is highly available. It's also advisable *not* to manage the Veeam Agent backup by VBR for the server itself.

By the way, Veeam do support free and community editions on a best-effort basis (which is very generous imho), so you could try that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but VBR can do network restores, it is just encountering this error before the Volume Level Restore wizard displays. I do have a support ticket open with them however there has been no response.

Comment: Yes, but the giveaway is the `localhost` VBR server - you cannot access the VBR repository when the VBR server is down. As mentioned, Veeam support for freeware is best effort - when there's no response you can try again later. If you depend on that software you should seriously consider getting paid support.

Comment: That isn't correct. The VBR server isn't down, it is continuing to run and back up other devices on the network. And it can be pinged from the device. The recovery process isn't getting far enough to tell it where the backup is located. The `localhost` error is happening as the recovery process prepares to launch the wizard. Veeam closed the ticket today without response. I am not expecting them to support it directly but a community support forum would be nice. They prohibit that which is why I am asking here. Perhaps a customer had encountered this and could shed some light on the issue.